# Dota 2 Error in Ubuntu 17.04: Required OpenGL extension "GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc" is not supported. Please update your OpenGL driver

Tags: drivers, games, steam, opengl

After I upgraded to Ubuntu 17.04 64-bit from Ubuntu 16.10 64-bit, I got this error when opening Dota 2:

```
Required OpenGL extension "GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc" is not supported. Please update your OpenGL driver.
```

This is only affecting my Dota 2 game while my other game in Steam, like Insurgeny works fine.

How to update OpenGL driver in Ubuntu 17.04 64-bit?

I'm using Dell Optiplex 3020 desktop.

Here are some details:

Memory: 4 GB
Processor: Intel Core i3-4130 CPU @ 3.40 GHz x 4
Graphics: Intel Haswell, Intel HD 4600
OS Type: 64-bit
Disk: 500 GB

Here are my graphics details:

```
~$ glxinfo | grep OpenGL

OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Haswell
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 17.2.0-devel
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 17.2.0-devel
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.1 Mesa 17.2.0-devel
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.10
OpenGL ES profile extensions:


~$  LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose glxinfo 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep so$

libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/tls/i965_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so
```

Comment: It would be worth adding the output of `glxinfo | grep OpenGL` (details of your OpenGL status) and `LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose glxinfo 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep so$` (details of your graphics driver) to your question.

Comment: Your output looks ok. A quick search appears to suggest it's something to do with a patent. Do you have the package `libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0` installed? I believe it should be installed by default, but if not it may be worth trying to install it using `sudo apt install libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0`. It sounds like this package adds that extension to Mesa.

Comment: Hi gsxruk, fixed it with the installation of libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0 courtesy of user665521.  Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0
```

Fixed my openGL error for DOTA on ubuntu 17.4 Intel CPU

Comment: Fixed mine too with this installation.  Thank you very much.

Comment: for me it was with `libtxc-dxtn-s2tc` (not libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0) but the command was automatically corrected. It did the solve the same issue. My video card is aver basic intel GPU for laptop ( VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display (rev 0e)).